# Unable to install h5py in virtualenv with pip3

Tags: package-management, python

I'm a beginner having trouble installing h5py.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and working in a virtualenv with pip3 and Python 3.6.9

I did the following installations in the virtualenv:

~$pip3 install -U pkgconfig

~$pip3 install -U cython

~$pip3 install -U numpy grpcio absl-py py-cpuinfo psutil portpicker six mock requests gast

~$pip3 list –local is:
absl-py            1.0.0
certifi            2021.10.8
charset-normalizer 2.0.9
Cython             0.29.25
gast               0.5.3
grpcio             1.42.0
idna               3.3
mock               4.0.3
numpy              1.19.5
pip                21.3.1
pkgconfig          1.5.5
portpicker         1.5.0
psutil             5.8.0
py-cpuinfo         8.0.0
requests           2.26.0
setuptools         58.5.3
six                1.16.0
urllib3            1.26.7
wheel              0.37.0

I then did the following installations, also in the virtualenv:

~$pip3 install -U h5py

The first error encountered was

Using cached h5py-3.1.0.tar.gz (371 kB)
Installing build dependencies ...  [?25l-     done
Getting requirements to build wheel ...  [?25ldone
Installing backend dependencies ...  [?25l-     ****error****
****ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:****

Thank you for any advise in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install build-dependencies for the [python3-h5py](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3-h5py) package.
At first you need to enable Source Code repositories in Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and then run below commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep python3-h5py
```

then retry h5py installation by pip3.

Comment: Thnak you for the very clear instructions. Unfortunately, the identical error results. If it is relevant the contents of pyvenv.cfg is:
home = /usr
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.6.9.final.0
virtualenv = 20.10.0
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = /usr
base-exec-prefix = /usr
base-executable = /usr/bin/python3

Answer (score 0):

I found a YouTube video that solved my problem. It seems to have been something to do with first installing the correct versions of some other modules.

The YouTube video is by Islander Robotics:  https://youtu.be/ynK-X5IPu1A

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here - please consider updating your answer to include the essential steps necessary to fix the issue, citing the YouTube link